# cannot change theme android

Tags: android, themes

For some reason I can't change the theme on my app. I want the light theme, but the following line in styles.xml doesn't change the theme.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

Am I missing something simple? It looks like the styles.xml setting is being overridden somewhere else.

Thanks.

Comment: change it in  values-v11, v14... also

Answer (score 0):

Look at your AndroidManifest.xml file, there should be a line like below, change the theme from there.

```
    <manifest>
            <application android:theme="@style/Green" />
                <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's still showing the dark theme.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but I can't find any code that overwrites it.

Comment: try to search `inflate` word on your project

Comment: ok then its impossible, please have a good look on your AndroidManifest and be sure you dont have any other style choices.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This was a problem with the AndroidManifest.xml file, not a code over-ride.